# multiplying elements in a 3x4 matrix individually in python 3 using loops (no numpy)

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to make a matrix that is 3 rows by 4 columns and includes the numbers 1-12. Would then like to multiply those numbers by a factor to make a new matrix.

```
def matrix(x):
    matrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
    new_matrix=[[x*1,x*2,x*3],[x*4,x*5,x*6],[x*7,x*8,x*9],[x*10,x*11,x*12]]
    print(new_matrix)
```

This approach works, however it does not use loops, I'm looking for an approach that uses loops, something like this:

```
 def matrix(x):
     for i in range(3):
         matrix.append([])
         for j in range(4):
             matrix[i].append(0)
             return matrix
```

Comment: Add description of the error/result you are currently getting.

Comment: There isn't a error, but I forgot to include that it has to be done using loops and without numpy, I will make an edit rn

Comment: Looks like your matrix is transposed. Normally, the first index is the row, the second is the column.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use explicit loops for something like this (unless you really want to). List comprehensions are a much more efficient way to generate lists, and have a similar syntax to a for loop:

Here is a comprehension for generating any MxN matrix containing the numbers up to `M * N`:

```
def matrix(m, n):
    return [[x+1 for x in range(row * n, (row + 1) * n)] for row in range(m)]
```

Here is a comprehension for multiplying the nested list returned by `matrix` by some factor:

```
def mult(mat, fact):
    return [[x * fact for x in row] for row in mat]
```

Here is the result for your specific 3x4 case:

```
>>> m = matrix(3, 4)
>>> print(m)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>> m2 = mult(m, 2)
>>> print(m2)
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [10, 12, 14, 16], [18, 20, 22, 24]]
```

If you want the indices to be swapped as in your original example, just swap the inputs `m` and `n`:

```
>>> matrix(4, 3)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

`mult` will work the same for any nested list you pass in.